# Getting remote exception with workmanager

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I have implemented workmanager that runs a task after one hour periodically. After making live it is working fine for all devices but for some devices I am getting few exceptions like:

```
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.scheduleAsPackage (JobSchedulerService.java:871)
  at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule (JobSchedulerService.java:2554)
  at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub.onTransact (IJobScheduler.java:60)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:731)
```

Can any one help in solving this issue or if someone else is also facing this issue please mention.

Comment: Can you please post your code of work manager class.

Comment: have you added process tag in manifest service

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the

```
Error: requested job be persisted without"
                            + " holding RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.
```

check have set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

permission in your manifest.